# manipulating std class objects as arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, api, object

I've pulled out prices from an api calling a list of houses. I'm stuck as to how to manipulate the individual entries in the 'std class object' (which has all the appearance of an array, but isn't)...

My question is how can I selectively access the data in the std class object and filter it down so that I only have an array consisting of:

latitude-values, 
longditude-values and price-values

My curl call is working and I can dump the data using print_r. That data looks like this:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [result_count] => 199
    [longitude] => -0.092534
    [area_name] => 
    [listing] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [image_caption] => Exterior Cgi.Jpg
                    [status] => for_sale
                    [num_floors] => 0
                    [listing_status] => sale
                    [num_bedrooms] => 3
                    [latitude] => 51.48961
                    [num_bathrooms] => 3
                    [post_town] => London
                    [outcode] => SE1
                    [last_published_date] => 2014-03-12 03:00:57
                    [county] => London
                    [price] => 5000000
                    [listing_id] => 32200697
                )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
            ...
            )
        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
            ...
            )
```

I have worked out how to print an individual value with:

```
print $data->listing[0]->price;
```

but I can't get the foreach statements looking at all of the data to work:

```
//e.g.
foreach ($data->listing->item as $item){
  print "<li>$item->title</li>\n";
}
//or
foreach($data->listing as $key => $val)
{
echo "Price: ".$key->price;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use of `$data->listing as $item` will do the trick:

```
foreach($data->listing as $item)
{
   echo "Price: ".$item->price;
}
```

To work with `SDTClass` containers as arrays, you can freely cast them to arrays:

```
$item = (array) $item ;
$item['price']; //Access its properties.
```

Comment: Nice - Hadn't realised that would also work with things like: echo "longitude: ".$item->longitude; echo "latitude: ".$item->latitude; echo "num_bedrooms: ".$item->num_bedrooms; - That's really helpful. Is it best practise to keep curl data as objects and access it this way or to switch it to an array format (which I'm more familiar with)?